# Why does TypeScript pack a class in an IIFE?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-5, iife

Here is a TypeScript class:

```
class Greeter {
    public static what(): string {
        return "Greater";
    }

    public subject: string;

    constructor(subject: string) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public greet(): string {
        return "Hello, " + this.subject;
    }
}
```

It is transpiled to IIFE when TS targets ES5:

```
var Greeter = /** @class */ (function () {
    function Greeter(subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }
    Greeter.what = function () {
        return "Greater";
    };
    Greeter.prototype.greet = function () {
        return "Hello, " + this.subject;
    };
    return Greeter;
}());
```

However, it generally works in the same way when it is presented as a constructor function. Which, of course, looks more JavaScriptish and handwritten :)

```
function Greeter(subject) {
    this.subject = subject;
}
Greeter.what = function () {
    return "Greater";
};
Greeter.prototype.greet = function () {
    return "Hello, " + this.subject;
};
```

Usage:

Both blocks of code work in the same way:

```
Greater.what();  // -> "Greater"
var greater = new Greater("World!");
greater.greet(); // -> "Hello, World!
```

What is the benefit or motives to pack it in IIFE?

I made a naive benchmark:

```
console.time("Greeter");
for(let i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) {
    new Greeter("world" + i);
}
console.timeEnd("Greeter");
```

It showed virtually the same instantiation speed. Of course, we cannot expect any difference, because the IIFE is resolved only once.

I was thinking that maybe it is because of closure, but the IIFE doesn't take arguments. It must not be a closure.

Comment: @charlietfl TS [doesn't use the IIFE to hide `private` fields](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Foo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20public%20name%20%3D%20%22%22%3B%0A%20%20%20%20private%20_name%20%3D%20%22%22%3B%0A%7D), actually. In JS they are all public.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

TypeScript will pass arguments to the IIFE in cases where there is inheritance between classes. For example, the closure below is used when `Greeter` extends a `BaseGreeter` class:

```
var Greeter = /** @class */ (function (_super) {
    // __extends is added by the TS transpiler to simulate inheritance
    __extends(Greeter, _super);
    function Greeter(subject) {
        var _this = _super.call(this) || this;
        _this.subject = subject;
        return _this;
    }
    Greeter.What = function () {
        return "Greater";
    };
    Greeter.prototype.greet = function () {
        return "Hello, " + this.subject;
    };
    return Greeter;
}(BaseGreeter));
```

Answer (score 12):

It's done to preserve native class behavior in edge cases like this, where someone tries to use class `Greeter` before it's defined:

```
// this is javascript code, not TypeScript

console.log(Greeter.What());

class Greeter {
}

Greeter.What = function What() {
    return "Greater";
}
```

With native class implementation, this should print `ReferenceError: Greeter is not defined`.

When transpiled and wrapped in IIFE, the result is close enough: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'What' of undefined`.

Without IIFE, unwrapped function is [hoisted](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function#Function_declaration_hoisting) and name `Greeter` is in scope before it's defined, so the different error is produced: `TypeError: Greeter.What is not a function`

Note that IIFE is not used to hide private instance or class properties because it's not necessary anyway. When transpiled, instance properties are assigned as properties for `this` inside the constructor, and static properties are assigned as properties of `Greeter` object - no variables are created.

Comment: A `var` won't get hoisted

Comment: Yes, the other answer is the correct one - you have to be able to introduce a name to refer to a base class, because for example base class might be a [mixin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Mix-ins). IIFE is the only way to safely introduce a name which will not conflict with anything in the outer scope.

Comment: I think both answers are right about different things. Yeah, `var` isn't hoisted but `function Greeter` by itself (as the OP showed) would be, which I thought was artem's point here. Also appreciate the point that TS doesn't actually use this for private fields.