# Why does compiled Angular code use closures instead of classes?

Tags: javascript, angular

Learning about closures at the moment and and noticed Angular component Typescript classes get compiled to closure functions.  Is there any particular reason for the use of closures over Javascript classes? e.g. compiled AppComponent.ts from a brand new project.

```
var AppComponent = /** @class */ (function () {
   function AppComponent() {
       this.title = 'My App';
   }
   AppComponent.prototype.ngOnInit = function () {
   };
   AppComponent = tslib__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["__decorate"]([
    Object(_angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__["Component"])({
        selector: 'app-root',
        template: __webpack_require__(/*! ./app.component.html */ "./src/app/app.component.html"),
        styles: [__webpack_require__(/*! ./app.component.scss */ "./src/app/app.component.scss")]
    }),
    tslib__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__["__metadata"]("design:paramtypes", [])
    ], AppComponent);
    return AppComponent;
}());
```

I realise closures have various uses and encapsulation is one of them, so why not use classes when what you are trying to achieve is a class anyway.

Thanks.

Comment: Because it's configured to compile/transpile to an earlier versions of JS. ES6 is not supported in IE.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does TypeScript pack a class in an IIFE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56086411/why-does-typescript-pack-a-class-in-an-iife)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because a `function` is compatible with Internet Explorer and other outdated browsers, but the `class` keyword is not. `class` can only be used in environments that support ES6. So, for compatibility, "classes" are transformed into immediately invoked functions.